# Task has encountered an exception in user code. SSIS Script Task

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I have a script task that creates and sends email to different users. 
The code itself works fine when executed in Visual Studio.

But when this code placed in Script Task - it gives me an error:

[image]

I found that one of the reasons could be "Main" entry point on script task. But this was already set by default.

[image]

Also read that might need some change in Microsoft Header or something, but not sure what is it.

```
  #region Namespaces
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using System.Security.Policy;
    #endregion

    namespace ST_ff2838a07b8b464fa4f787c388ad3857
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
        /// or parent of this class.
        /// </summary>


   //Do I need to change something here???  

//[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
        public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
        {


            /// <summary>
            /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
            /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
            /// To open Help, press F1.
            /// </summary>
            public void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string UnderwriterName = "SELECT DISTINCT [Underwriter] FROM [ExcessRenewal].[dbo].[Renewals]";
                string connectionString =
```

Comment: Did you copy this code in? The namespaces don't match.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is looking for the namespace associated with the Project:

```
ST_......75700c1
```

but i think you copied in code over it and have a different namespace now:

```
ST_ff2838a07b8b464fa4f787c388ad3857
```

just replace the namespace in the script with your project namespace and I think you will be good to go.

Comment: I tried to change namespace to  ST_`f575df1df9704300ae9d3c0d975700c1` but no success yet.

Comment: Start over with a new script task. Paste in your namespace then paste your code